# Use of a generic in protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to make a data source protocol for a generic component, but I can't work out how to correctly use associatedtype and typealias. Whenever I try to define the data source in the component it gives compile error:

***Protocol 'SampleDataSource' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"***

Here is a snippet of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
public protocol SampleDataSource {
    associatedtype ObjectType
    func objectAtIndex(index: Int) -> ObjectType
}

public class SampleComponent<T> {
    typealias ObjectType = T
    
    var dataSource: SampleDataSource? = nil // <-- This line has error
}
```

Comment: The error says everything you need to know. Protocols with associated types can be used only as constraints (e.g. in `where` clausules), they cannot be used as variables.

Comment: In other words, you can do: `class SampleComponent<T: SampleDataSource> {...}` and define `var dataSource: T` (no need for typealias)...

Comment: That also means that you have to start by defining a concrete implementation of `SampleDataSource`.

Comment: I think I understand now, thank you both for your help.